# There is no row at position 0, exception

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am having a problem while login, the registered user's name, email and password is saved in the database and the email is the username. When i am logging through email and password it shows the error "There is no row at position 0."
Here's my code :

```
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from userinfo where username='" + t1.Text.ToString() + "' and password='" + t2.Text.ToString() + "'", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "abc");
        Session["name"] = ds.Tables["abc"].Rows[0][1].ToString();
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because reason is the no one record found in Db same as a passing username and password and you can directly access so its give exception. Please add one if condition below like.

```
 con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username = @username AND password = @password", con);
    cmd.Paramater.AddWithValue("@username", t1.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Paramater.AddWithValue("@password", t2.Text.ToString());
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds, "abc");
    if(ds.Tables["abc"].Rows.Count>0)
    {
         Session["name"] = ds.Tables["abc"].Rows[0][1].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Your query is open for `SQL Injection attack`!

Comment: @downvoter, Why down vote? No any explanation about SQL Injection in Question.

Comment: @lazzy, Yes you are right but he gives suggestion in comment not to do down vote without wrong answer.

Comment: thanx @Kaushik Maheta and all for your support and sorry for not replying, there was a problem in internet. I have tried all the above solution's but when i am logging from the correct username and password its not returning any row and executing the else part is executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username = @username AND password = @password", con);
cmd.Paramater.AddWithValue("@username", t1.Text.ToString());
cmd.Paramater.AddWithValue("@password", t2.Text.ToString());
con.open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.read();
if(dr.hasRows){
Session["name"] = dr["username"].ToString();
}
con.close();
```

Try not to throw variables into a sql command. SQL injection and all. Try and pass the paramater

Comment: i have also tried passing parameter, but the same exception is generating, @JiraiyaUK

Comment: Did you put the IF statement in? it looks like your programming is crashing as there is no row to return.

Comment: yes i am giving the if statement every time and the else part is executing.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because there are no records in that table.

There are no rows, so there is no `Rows[0]`.

Try something like this:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username = @1 AND password = @2", con);
    cmd.Paramater.AddWithValue("@1", t1.Text);
    cmd.Paramater.AddWithValue("@2", t2.Text);

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds, "abc");

    if(ds.Tables["abc"].Rows.Any())
         Session["name"] = ds.Tables["abc"].Rows[0][1].ToString();

    con.Close(); 
}
```

You should use parameters when constructing SQL queries to avoid injection attacks.

Don't forget that `SqlConnection` is `IDisposable`, so should be in a `using` statement (you might already be doing this, but i've included it here just in case).

It also looks like the user's password is being compared to the input from a `TextBox` (or a similar control)? If so, the user's password should not be stored in plain text in the database as this is a security issue. Consider hashing the stored password, doing the same with the user's input, and comparing that instead.
This wasn't part of the question, I know, but worth pointing out just in case.

Comment: can u explain me how to hash password in database as well as user's input.

Comment: OWASP has some guidance that might be useful https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_Security_Cheat_Sheet, or you can raise another question if that does not give you what you need.